# Azure function TimerTrigger result code in Application Insights is always success

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I've got a simple C# Azure Function using a timer trigger to run every X minutes. No output binding.

In application insights, the function is always in *success* with a *result code* of 0:

[image: Here]

[Despite having called the .Error() of the TraceWriter several times.]

I'd like to get the correct final status in application insights but I don't see how to do it. Documentation never talks about that :-/
Can someone guide me how to do it in C# ?

I tried to set `Environment.ExiCode` but same result.
I also tried to change return type to `int` but then the function isn't called anymore. I suppose because its the way to [declare an output binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings#c-example) for the azure function itself.

Here is my function:

```
[FunctionName("SendToOfflineArchive")]
public static void Run([TimerTrigger("%TimerInterval%")]TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

    // do stuff

    int nbErrors = 7;
    //return nbErrors;
}
```

It would be great to have a result code other than 0... Like the number of errors (an integer).

Comment: Hi Thibault, how did you create this function using Visual studio or directly on the portal? I think TraceWriter is old signature. Take a look at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook

Comment: It's a 7 months-"old" project using the Functions 1.x and working fine. However same issue with version 2.x. Anyhow the logger is not the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Function is considered failed if it threw an exception (there is an embedded integration between AF and AI and it considers successfully executed function a "success"). Logging an error as a trace should yield corresponding Trace message in Application Insights if logging forwarding is enabled.

Comment: Ok good idea! It worked: http://tof.cx/images/2019/02/01/875b772896503946c182d189aacd30b3.png Yes log forwarding is enabled (actually it's the only way to have history of execution in azure function) and I saw calls to .Error() in invocation details. My point was regarding the global result code status (see screenshot). How can I set the result code?

Comment: In Azure Functions v2 [you should be able](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/issues/759#issuecomment-426687852) to configure Telemetry Initializer (receives all telemetry passing through) and modify response code of the RequestTelemetry based on the exception you had, I guess. Something like `if (telemetry is RequestTelemetry request) {request.ResponseCode = ...}`